# count and echo on activities

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have database which stores an activity type (swimming, running, soccer, tennis and basketball)under `task_cstm`.

Another database stores `salesman name`, `date_start` and `date_due` stored in tasks.

When I run on phpMyAdmin,

```
SELECT COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm
LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = tasks_cstm.id_c
where tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ="swimming" and assigned_user_id="abcdefg"
```

I got the result that I want:

However I place this into a PHP file which allows the user to select the `SALESMAN` and `DAT` to see how many activities being promoted by the salesman during the period nothing being shown:

```
$result = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c, 
COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm tc 
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.id = tc.id_c 
WHERE activity_type_c='swimming' AND date_start>='$st' 
AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")

echo "<tr><td>".$result."</td></tr>";
```

Could someone please help me and give me some guidance?

Comment: how can we know what this is doing:`$GLOBALS['db']->query`

Comment: The First issue is that you are passing a table alias to query, right on "FROM tasks_cstm tc", you should call tc.activity_type_c,count(tc.activity_type_c), i guess the error was that you are getting a MYSQL error and are not retriving the erros to see whats happening, everytime you query cannot be processed, it ill return only false, you should retrive errors by yourself to get exacty what's going.

Comment: So why don't you try your actual query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: cause i had the field of variable of user and date as input from another php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `mysqli_*` extensions, please try this:

```
$result = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c, 
COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) FROM tasks_cstm tc 
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.id = tc.id_c 
WHERE activity_type_c='swimming' AND date_start>='$st' 
AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($row);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

The key issue I see from what you have presented you are jumping directly from the `$result` to just echoing the `$result` instead of running something like `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` to actually parse the values.

But it’s still unclear what you expect this to be:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$result."</td></tr>";
```

Should that be one row of data? If so, which piece of data?  Or are those `<tr><td>` and `</td></tr>` just a per data holder?  If so maybe this would work for one item per row:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  echo '<tr><td>';
  echo $row['tasks_cstm.activity_type_c'];
  echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Or maybe this which sets a table cell for each item within a larger row:

```
echo '<tr>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  echo '<td>';
  echo $row['tasks_cstm.activity_type_c'];
  echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Hi, what happen is that i trying to count a single activity which result in i write the $result 5 times with activity_type_c change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c, 
COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) AS totalCount FROM tasks_cstm tc 
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.id = tc.id_c 
WHERE activity_type_c='swimming' AND date_start>='$st' 
AND date_due<='$dt' AND assigned_user_id='$salesman' AND t.id=tc.id_c")

echo "<tr><td>".print_r($result)."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much as ur totalcount input help me think of a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you get All Row data in $result if yes then write below code you will get result row data 
while($ row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $ row[0] . " " . $row[1];echo "
";}
and If you dont get data in $result then first check connection and then execute query.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys for all your help. i got the result that i wanted.

What i did was to add to 
...SELECT tasks_cstm.activity_type_c, COUNT( tasks_cstm.activity_type_c ) AS TOTALCOUNT(0-4) for each result.

and for every single result(0-4) i need to have another fetchbyassoc so i input

```
$r0= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result0);
$r1= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result1);
$r2= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result2);
$r3= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result3);
$r4= $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result4);
```

and also i echo out using this

```
echo "<tr>
<td>".$r0['totalCount0']."</td>
<td>".$r1['totalCount1']."</td>
<td>".$r2['totalCount2']."</td>
<td>".$r3['totalCount3']."</td>
<td>".$r4['totalCount4']."</td>
</tr>";
```

and yes i got the answer i need. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ALL UR HELP (^3^)